# Specifying JRE location for Java WebStart application

Tags: windows, java, java-web-start

Is there a generic way to point to a specific JRE/JDK to run a JWS application?
I'm looking into specifying the actual location of the JRE, not only it's version via Java SE element of JNLP file. Think of choosing between Oracle and IBM JREs with the same version you have locally.

One way I can think of is simply create a shortcut to the particular javaws passing the jnlp file location as a parameter, so it would be easy for the end user to launch it from his desktop. Is there any other way to achieve this?

JRE may or may be not registered in the system, so that is a difficulty too.

Comment: I believe being able to this would represent a security vulnerability.  You don't want an attacker to be able to specify a known-unsafe JRE, e.g., one shipped with a third-party application.

Answer (score 1):

Using JNLP file syntax as far as I know you can reffer to version of java library only (+installation path for the case client doesn't have it installed yet).
There is no such option to force directory/vendor where/whose JRE is to be used.

What I think you would miss is the flexibility and idea of one of the basic JWS concepts, that you just provide your app, and technology takes care of execution environment, updates, ... (From the real life apps I know it's not so straightforward with JWS, but I think that was the original intent :))

And yes, I think partially you provided one of the possible answers yourself: write your own code creating shortcut to whatever you want to achieve and start the shortcut the next time app is beeing started, or start the shortcutted app silently in the background to prevent any need for app restart.

From the real life experience, we did similar solution with the programically created shortuct (although vendor was not the case for us).